# VIM NerdCommenter: How to toggle comments in the visual mode?

Tags: vim, nerdcommenter

What is the command to toggle comments in the Visual mode? The `cc` command allows me to comment in the visual mode. I couldn't find a command to un-comment.

```
[count]<leader>cc |NERDComComment|
```

PS: I use `c` command to toggle comments in `normal` mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
[count]<Leader>cu NERDComUncommentLine
Uncomments the selected line(s).
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed the last line when I RTFM!